# Structuring the data warehouse?

Tags: database, database-design, data-structures, data-warehouse, etl

I need an advice for creating my DW. I have some experience in creating DW (using Pentaho as BI server), I made an array of scheduled database queries which creates 4 dimension tables and 1 fact table (for sales reports).
Now, there is a need for spreading out DW (for import, warehouse, logistic reports), so my question is:
 **Do I have to make more fact tables for each department (and dimension tables for those), or there is some other structuring model?**
Of course, this time it will be done using ETL tool, but need general advice.

Thanks,
Stevan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A fact table represents a process or events that you want to analyze.

If there is not a new process or event that you want to analyze, then you do not need a new fact table.

Perhaps you could give us some more details about what you are analyzing...

Comment: Thanks Neil. Ok, sure, here is my example: Company has tree main departments: Sales, Import, and Logistic. They have some common tables (in operational db), but main ones are different. Everyone combos with finance and HR. Is that 3 fact tables? What you meant by process or event? Sales is a process.. I guess

Comment: @StevanPopov Examples of business processes: retail sales, inventory, procurement, order management, accounting, CRM, HR management (taken from [The Data Warehouse Toolkit: The Definitive Guide to Dimensional Modeling](http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/1118530802/) that I highly recommend - if you don't have time for the entire book, read at least 3 or 4 chapters).